# How to find overall grades and then sort using qsort()

Tags: c

In C i'm creating a grade system and Im stuck on how to get the weighed grade of homework and tests separately then add them to an overall grade. There are 10 hw and 5 test with each hw being 5% of the overall grade and each test being 10% of the overall grade making 100% total. In my code I randomly generate each test and hw grade now I want to add up hw and test scores separately, find the weighted grade for both categories, then add them to show overall weighted grade. Im stuck on getting the sums for each test and where to put that in my code.

here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define ID_LEN 10
#define NAME_LEN 21
#define HW_SCORES 10
#define TEST_SCORES 5

typedef struct {
    char id[ID_LEN];
    char fname[NAME_LEN];
    char lname[NAME_LEN];
    char mi;
    unsigned char hw_scores[HW_SCORES];
    unsigned char test_scores[TEST_SCORES];
//modify struct stu_rect_type
} stu_rec_type;

int idcmp(const void *a, const void *b) {

    stu_rec_type *pa = (stu_rec_type *) a;
    stu_rec_type *pb = (stu_rec_type *) b;
    return -(strcmp(pa->id, pb->id));
}
int lnamecmp(const void *a, const void *b) {

    stu_rec_type *pa = (stu_rec_type *) a;
    stu_rec_type *pb = (stu_rec_type *) b;
    return -(strcmp(pa->lname, pb->lname));
}
int scorecmp(const void *a, const void *b) {

    stu_rec_type *pa = (stu_rec_type *) a;
    stu_rec_type *pb = (stu_rec_type *) b;
    int total_a = 0, total_b = 0;
    int i;
    for (i=0; i < HW_SCORES; i++) {
            total_a += 0.1*pa->hw_scores[i];
            total_b += 0*1*pb->hw_scores[i];
    }
    for (i=0; i < TEST_SCORES; i++) {
            total_a += 0.05*pa->test_scores[i];
            total_b += 0.05*pb->test_scores[i];
    }
    if (total_a == total_b)
            return strcmp(pa->lname, pb->lname);
        //Sorting in descending order
        else  if(total_a > total_b)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
}

void print_rec(stu_rec_type *rec_ptr) {
        int j;
        printf("ID: %s\n", rec_ptr->id);
    printf("NAME: %s %c. %s\n", rec_ptr->fname, rec_ptr->mi, rec_ptr->lname );
    printf("HW SCORES:\n");
    for (j=0; j <HW_SCORES; j++){
        printf("%4d", rec_ptr->hw_scores[j]);
        if ( (j+1)%10 ==0)
                printf("\n");
    }
    printf("TEST SCORES:\n");
    for (j=0; j <TEST_SCORES; j++){
        printf("%4d", rec_ptr->test_scores[j]);
        if ( (j+1)%10 ==0)
                printf("\n");
    }
}

int main(){
    //prompt user to input number of students
    int CLASS_SIZE;
    printf("Enter the number of students : ");
    scanf("%d",&CLASS_SIZE);
    stu_rec_type *cs3500_class;
    //malloc to allocate momeory of student records
    // Dynamically allocating memory for an array of student records.
    cs3500_class=(stu_rec_type *)malloc(sizeof(stu_rec_type)*CLASS_SIZE);
    int i, j, k;
    char *ptr;
    stu_rec_type *stu_ptr;
    int n = 700000000;
    char id[10];
    srand(time(NULL));
    for(i = 0; i < CLASS_SIZE; i++) {
    // generate ids
    //ptr = (char *) &(cs3500_class[i].id);
    // sprintf(ptr, "%i", ++n);
      sprintf((char *)&(cs3500_class[i].id), "%i", ++n);
    // generate the first names
        cs3500_class[i].fname[0] = 'A' + rand()%26;
    k = rand()%(NAME_LEN-1);
    for (j=0; j < k; j++)
        cs3500_class[i].fname[j+1] = 'a' + rand()%26;
        cs3500_class[i].fname[k+1] = '\0';
    // generate the last names
        cs3500_class[i].lname[0] = 'A' + rand()%26;
    k = rand()%(NAME_LEN-1);
    for (j=0; j < k; j++)
        cs3500_class[i].lname[j+1] = 'a' + rand()%26;
        cs3500_class[i].lname[k+1] = '\0';
    // generate mi
        cs3500_class[i].mi = 'A' + rand()%26;
    // generate hw scores between 10-20 max being 20
    for (j=0; j<HW_SCORES; j++)
        cs3500_class[i].hw_scores[j] = (rand() % 10) + 11;
    // generate test scores between 50-100 max being 100
    for (j=0; j<TEST_SCORES; j++)
        cs3500_class[i].test_scores[j] = 51 + (rand()%50);
    }
    // displaying the first 5 records
    for (i = 0; i < CLASS_SIZE; i++) {
            print_rec(&cs3500_class[i]);
    printf("\n\n ");
    }
    // sort the records based on the 1st score
    //using qsort() in descending order
    printf("\n\nAfter qsort\n");
    qsort(cs3500_class, CLASS_SIZE, sizeof(stu_rec_type), scorecmp);
    // display the first 5 records
    for (i = 0; i < CLASS_SIZE; i++) {
        print_rec(&cs3500_class[i]);
    printf("\n\n");
    }
    return 0;
```

[Here is the output as of now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKqCL.png)

I plan to show the grades in order of the ID number then after qsort I will show in order of highest grade.

Comment: `total_b += 0*1*pb->hw_scores[i];` - isn't ever going to amount to much. Just saying. And fyi, you're also missing `#include <string.h>`, where one finds `strcmp` and friends.

Comment: Either add a new computed field to the structure so that the weighted score is available without further computation or have the compare function call the score computation function twice each time it is called. One method takes up a little more memory; the other takes up quite a lot more CPU cycles.